# Dynamic Text Background Highlight Animation with Duration in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-animatable

I have stuck at this point to dynamically highlight some bunch of text in some duration. Like for example, I have this text :

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply a dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
```

I want the functionality to highlight this text background in a duration of 180sec.

**What I did is this:**

[Video link](https://vimeo.com/598806435)

The logic I used is that I created two states s1, s2 with s1 as an empty string, and s2 with the whole content. Stating timer, I am removing n number of characters from s2 and adding the same n number of characters in s1, and showing s1 and s2 together inside `<Text>`.

This feature is working but not correctly animating. I want some CSS transition-type smooth highlight animation for this feature to highlight this text completely in some duration.

Can anyone please help me to implement this feature using React Native Animations API?

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically start a new animation, you need a condition. You can use "Animated" from react-native. Instead of state, set a ref, and change the ref value.

```
import { Animated } from "react-native";

// this value can be animated one value to another
const animationRef = useRef<Animated.Value>(new Animated.Value(0));



if(condition){
    // pass array of animations
    Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(animationRef.current, {
            toValue: 1,
            // set the duration 
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: false
        }),
        // delay is optional
        Animated.delay(1000),
        Animated.timing(animationRef.current, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 500,
          // useNativeDriver:true, might not work with the all properties that you need to animate. true might improve animation performance

            useNativeDriver: false
        })
    ]).start();

 }
```

Now in jsx you need to set your component:

```
   // Touchable opacity cannot be animated
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
        <Animated.View
            style={[
                styles.itemBackground,
                {
                    backgroundColor: animationRef.current.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [0, 1],
                        // if value is 0 color:black, value is 1 color:white
                        outputRange: [colors.black, colors.white]
                    })
                }
            ]}
        />
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

Animated.View position should be absolute. Keep the dynamic part of CSS in the component, but you can keep other CSS in a different file.

```
 //styles.itemBackground:

 itemBackground: { position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't tried your solution yet, but I will try it now and respond to your solution ASAP.